# How to change WooCommerce customer-logout endpoint URL?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Any time a customer/user clicks on Logout from the Woocommerce account page, he/she is taken to a page I don't want. For example; `https://example.com/my-account/cusomer-logout/` is the page the user lands on after clicking on Logout. But instead, I want the user to land on `https://example.com/my-page/customer-logout/`.

Although `https://example.com/my-account/cusomer-logout/` is the page I want the user/customer to be when they log in.

Any solution will be very much appreciated.

Regards
Trinity

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got it correctly but this may help you : https://pixelgrade.com/docs/listable/header-and-footer/create-log-link-menu/

on my own I am doing something similar with a shortcode (the php code should be placed on a child theme functions.php file if you need this).

```
function client_login()
{
    $html = '<div class="reg-user-widget">';
    if (is_user_logged_in())
    {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $html .= 'Welcome ' . esc_html($current_user->display_name);
        $html .= ' <a href="' .wc_logout_url( $redirect ).'">Log Out</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        $html .= 'Hi there. <a href="/my-account">Log In / Register</a>';
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('user_login_area', 'client_login');
```